# Amphp : Run many async loops with same connection (eventstore client)

Tags: php, amphp

I'm using eventstore client which uses amphp. I need inside my application to reuse the connection in many parts.

So I created a connection provider:

```
public function getConnection(): EventStoreConnection
{
    if ($this->connection) {
        return $this->connection;
    }
    $this->connection = $this->createConnection();
    wait($this->connection->connectAsync());

    return $this->connection;
}
```

And then I use this connection at many places:

```
\Amp\Loop::run(function () use ($eventStoreEvents, $streamName) {
    $connection = $this->connectionProvider->getConnection();

    // Creation of an event stream
    yield $connection->appendToStreamAsync($streamName, ExpectedVersion::ANY, $eventStoreEvents);
    // sleep(10); // This sleep does not work, code continue like nothing happend
});

\Amp\Loop::run(function () use ($streamName, $aggregateFqcn, &$aggregateRoot) {

    $start = 0;
    $count = \Prooph\EventStore\Internal\Consts::MAX_READ_SIZE;

    $connection = $this->connectionProvider->getConnection();

    do {
        $events = [];
        /** @var StreamEventsSlice $streamEventsSlice */
        $streamEventsSlice = yield $connection
            ->readStreamEventsForwardAsync(
                $streamName,
                $start,
                $count,
                true
            );

        if (!$streamEventsSlice->status()->equals(SliceReadStatus::success())) {
            dump($streamEventsSlice); // Event stream does not exist
            // Error here: the event stream doesn't exist at this point.
            throw new RuntimeGangxception('Impossible to generate the aggregate');
        }
    } while (! $streamEventsSlice->isEndOfStream());
});
```

The problem: **it seems that the first request is not over but the second loop starts already**. The sleep uncommented doesn't have any effect!

But the event stream is finally created with the related events inside, so the first request worked.

If I start a connection then close then start a new one, it works. But it's slow, due to handshake overhead on each new connection.

I tried a similar example with the WebSocket library of Amphp and it worked. Do you see anything wrong?

Here is my test with websocket that worked:

```
$connection = \Amp\Promise\wait(connect('ws://localhost:8080'));
Amp\Loop::run(function () use ($connection) {
   /** @var Connection $connection */
   yield $connection->send("Hello...");
   sleep(10); // This sleep works!
});

Amp\Loop::run(function () use ($connection) {
   /** @var Connection $connection */
   yield $connection->send("... World !");
});

$connection->close();
```

Comment: You shouldn't have two `Amp\Loop::run` as you only need 1 event loop (see https://amphp.org/amp/event-loop/api). I think you do not fully understand the concepts that are being used, as `yield` in the first context essentially means "don't go further than this until I'm ready" and allows the event loop to process other events, so the `sleep(10);` isn't reached/executed until after the `yield` above it is ready/returned.

Comment: The sleep is just some test. I notice same situation with differents tools leads to differents results. I use the yield to wait for the async work to end (I undersand it as a wait inside an amphp loop). The problem seems that.. It's actually not done!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prooph eventstore library is based on amphp but doesn't follow all principles: you can't wait for the connection to be ready. It will be even worse if you try to use it at scale, so don't try to wait for the promise is complete.

As an alternative, you can set a promise for later and check if the connection is null. That's what actually does the library internally to process further steps.

On my side, I decided to stop using this library. But as an alternative you can use the library that uses the HTTP client, it's also from the prooph team.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do makes no sense. You should read [amphp's documenation](https://amphp.org/amp/event-loop/).

Amp uses a global accessor for the event loop as there’s only one event loop for each application. It doesn’t make sense to have two loops running at the same time, as they would just have to schedule each other in a busy waiting manner to operate correctly.

That said, there is literally NO SECOND LOOP.

Comment: Using 2 loops is definitely not the best approach. But it makes sense. I figure out that eventstore client library from prooph does not work as expected. (yield does not actually wait for connection establishment) I suggest you to read documentation on the front page here https://amphp.org/amp/#preamble That said it's obvious this library will not fit my usecase since you're the main maintainer, I should just stop using it, and I will. Thanks for your time.